# Sulu : How to implement Changelog and Permission setting functionality in Sulu custom bundle

Tags: symfony, sulu

I created Sulu custom bundle in admin section.
Now I want to achieve implementation of the changelog and permission settings functionality same like existing sulu content bundle.
Appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have an own section explaining that in the [documentation](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/cookbook/securing-your-application.html).